# Autolayout Constraint unselected for Regular-Regular shows up as conflicts on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I have this constraint for Any-Any size class and I have unselected it for Regular-Regular with the hope that this constraint would not apply to iPad. Then I run the app on iPad simulator and get unsatisfiable constraints error on this constraint. Am I missing something? Isn't what I did supposed to disable this constraints for iPad?

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var const1Out: NSLayoutConstraint!

var const1: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    const1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item:... // Defining the complete constraint


    orientationDidChange()

}


func orientationDidChange()
{
    // Just iPad
    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .Regular && traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular {
        // Conditioning on iPad Portrait or Landscape 


        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
        {
             // activate to deactivate constraints either defined as vars or outlets
        }
        else
        {
             // activate to deactivate constraints either defined as vars or outlets
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after you have uninstalled this constraint, are you sure your view has enough constraints needed to be layouted correctly ?

Comment: switchto wR-hR size class and see if Xcode complains about missing constraints

Comment: The constraint shows grayed out in R-R and there is no complains.

Comment: are you doing some autolayout manipulations in code ?

Comment: I am doing auto layout manipulation in code as well.

Comment: This can be the source of problem. Can you show the code snippet where you are doing autolayout stuff  for the view which has that disabled constraint on iPads  ?

Comment: I added not the exact code since it's very long and I think it will be irrelevant. But I added the sort of things that I am doing in code.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble in UICollectionViewCell xib in Xcode 9. I found a workaround : uncheck "install" and check "wC hC", "wR hC" and "wC hR". It's worked for me but did'nt find how to make it work with "install" checkbox again